# dash application frontend debugging

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, plotly-dash

I am developing a website using dash framework. I got the errors from the browsers , but it is all about react.js, how this error to be interpreted to where the python codes are wrong?

e.g.

react_devtools_backend.js:2560 Warning: React does not recognize the `setProps` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `setprops` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

How can I find where is wrong in the python codes based on the information of the error shows in browser?

I would be grateful if you could share your experience how do you debug in dash apps frontend errors.